# Trying to set up automated deletion of post after a specified amount of time in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

i am setting up a basic blog website using laravel and i've managed to create the CRUD functions fine and link it to a db but i have been trying to set up a system where a post auto expires after a period of time. I did some searching and came across a couple of methods. One was using schedule in the kernel.php file but i couldn't follow and it didn't work, then i tried using Carbon and tried this

```
Post::where('updated_at','<',Carbon::subDays(5))->delete();
```

but it did not work. Then i found this

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->call(function () {
        Task::where('updated_at','<', Carbon::now())->delete();
    })->everyMinute();
}
```

this also did not work but i think it is due to me lacking the knowledge to implement it into my system, do i call it from the controller?
I am just looking for the best option to implement expiration and how to do it. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Please better define with "not work" means; that's incredibly vague. Did you get an error? Was nothing deleted? Etc etc. Note: `Carbon::subDays(5)` gives me an error `Method Carbon/Carbon::subDays does not exist.`. But `Carbon::now()->subDays(5)` works just fine, as does `(new Carbon())->subDays(5)`

Comment: do you have cron setup to call the scheduler? it doesn't run by itself, something has to run it

Comment: sorry for being so vague, yes thankyou as that fixes the issue and it works. in case i want to go a step further, how do i bring in cron?

Comment: The Scheduler class should work, not sure what `Task` is vs `Post`, and you're using `now()` instead of `now()->subDays(5)`, but beyond that, check the documentation on how to actually run the scheduler: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/scheduling. You need a CRON Tab running on your server.

Comment: It may be simpler and safer to use a scope - comparable to soft delete - whereby you have an expires_at field and a global scope on all posts.